# Lenovo IdeaPad P400 - Disabling the annoying requirement for the Fn key to use F1-F12

Tags: keyboard-layout

On Lenovo laptops, in order to use <kbd>F5</kbd> you need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> (same with <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>). It's really annoying and I'd like to reverse the situation. On Windows, a Lenovo driver could help:
http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge-S-series/Disable-Fn-Keys-E420/td-p/803609

How can I resolve this on Ubuntu 12.04? I couldn't find Lenovo drivers for Linux.

UPDATE:
Found a peculiar solution for this on Windows. Can anyone recommend a good equivalent for Xubuntu:
http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-Z-and-P-series/How-do-you-reset-the-function-keys-on-a-P500-ideapad-to-legacy/td-p/958995

Comment: You should get this option in BIOS.The driver must be changing that BIOS option.

Comment: Looked for it, doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

On my E540 I just press <kbd>Fn+Esc</kbd> keys to activate <kbd>FnLock</kbd> and <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> works as they should. I'v found it 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Doesn't work on my P400

Answer (score 0):

The option you are talking about involves going to BIOS > configuration > action keys (off)/Legacy mode (enable)
We need to ask Lenovo to give a BIOS update for the P400 though, there is no Legacy mode option..

Comment: No such option there. I am starting to get used to this backwards behavior I must admit.